# Rails 5 API mode: can't reach show action for a nested resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using rails 5.2.1 in API mode with 2.5.3.

I have the following `routes.rb` file..

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
    resource :groups, only: [:show]
  end
end
```

.. and the following `app/controllers/api/groups_controller.rb` file

```
class Api::GroupsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    binding.pry
  end
end
```

The following request `http://localhost:3000/api/groups` arrives in the controller's action properly, triggering the `binding.pry`.

The issue is that the following request `http://localhost:3000/api/groups/1` thraws a Routing error:

No route matches [GET] "/api/groups/1"

Why is that happening ?

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Comment: api_groups GET  /api/groups(.:format)                                                                 api/groups#show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to pass the `id` to show action, I guess probably you need this in your routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api do
     resources :groups, only: [:index, :show]
  end
end
```

and have `index` and `show` actions in your `Api::GroupsController`.

I suggest you go through [rails guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html). Understand the difference between `resource` and `resources`